udev rule for mounting usb drives read-only on a certain usb port
for some reasons I need USB drives to get mounted read-only from time to time. As I do have more than one USB port on my computer, I thought it would be a great idea to define one of them as a "read only port" (in best case also immutable by a dd usage of root, if possible) by making a udev rule.
Unfortunately, I have no idea ... Can somebody point me to the right direction?
Thank you ;)

Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about system configuration, not about programming, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  See Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on? for guidance.

Wasn't sure about where to post it, but as a lot of udev questions where already posted here without complaints ... will try to do my best next time.

Yes, there are a lot that need to be flagged as off-topic.  I'll start closing some of the obvious non-programming ones right now.
